# tablesort multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter dropdown using which I am able to select one element from it. I want to be able to select multiple elements. Is there a way to do it using table sorter ?

I tried looking up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943995/tablesorter-select-multiple-options-from-select-dropdown-menu-and-custom-time-fi) but I am not sure if it says of any direct way to do it. Also this [issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/717) seems to suggest that there is no direct way?

EDIT:

Code

```
        filter_functions : {
            0 : {
                "a" : function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return e===f; },
                "b" : function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return e===f; },
                "c" : function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return e===f; },
                "d" : function(e, n, f, i, $r) { return e===f; }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filter_formatter` option along with the [extra filter-formatter select2 code](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets-filter-formatter-select2.js) to use the [select2](http://select2.github.io/) plugin. [Here is a demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-select2.html).

```
filter_formatter : {
  // default settings on first column
  0 : function($cell, indx){
    return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2( $cell, indx, {
      // *** select2 filter formatter options ***
      cellText : '',    // Text (wrapped in a label element)
      match    : true,  // adds "filter-match" to header & modifies search
      value    : [],    // initial select2 values

      // *** ANY select2 options can be included below ***
      // (showing default settings for this formatter code)
      multiple : true,  // allow multiple selections
      width    : '100%' // reduce this width if you add cellText
    });
  }
}
```

**Note**: Please be aware that the `$.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2` function does not yet work with select2 v4.0.0 beta. Use select2 v3.4.6 included with the repsitory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not entirely comfortable with the file_formater yet. I have updated my code filter_function for the 0th column in my code. Is there a way to modify that? Nevertheless I am trying to modify the way you suggested.

Comment: I am able to exactly as it is now, except I am not able to remove the tag buttons. No closing symbol on the tags added. I mean it closes if I click on the left but the symbol 'x' to close is not being displayed. Any idea on this ?

Comment: Maybe you're missing the [select2 css & images](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2) - make sure to get it for v3.4.6.

Comment: Just a quick follow up question, although this now works perfectly fine, is there a way to embed say http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect.html into the table sorter to get multiselect?

Comment: Currently, to add a custom selector into the filter row you would need to add custom `filter_formatter` code to make it work properly - it would be a real pain unless you start with an existing code and modify it. In a upcoming update, you'll be able to define a completely custom filter row and just define a filter custom value which returns the value from the plugin you want to use. I'm just working out the kinks, so hopefully it won't be too much longer.